# Migrate Datastage to Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, datastage

I am a newbie in ETL. I have a requirement to migrate IBM DataStage to Informatica.

```
a. Please specify best tools to do this above scenario.
b. Before doing migration, please help me in mentioning the steps required before doing migration.
c. Drawbacks for this scenario.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no single solution work for your problem as migrating from one ETL to other is a nightmare. You have to consider lot of points.  Let me list few:

1. Understand current ETL process
2. Collect list of source and target system and types like flat file, RDBMS etc
3. Read the datastage mapping and prepare mapping specification - (transformation logic, lookup logic, join conditions, expressions)
4. Understand the datastage architecture - number of nodes, high availability, fail over etc
5. List of DB objects used like Stored procedures, functions etc

Once you understand these you can think about how you can implement this using Infa.

Comment: I have heard about "ANALYTIX DS" which will do ETL conversion tools for data integration, data management, enterprise application integration and big data software and services. Will it be suitable to my requirement.

Comment: I guess you need to contact Analytix for a PoC to find out.